# How to get NSArray object in NSString and send that object one by one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to send array object one by one.I save data in core data then I fetch it and now I want to send it one by one to the web service.
Hear is my code to fetch the object from core data and get it in array..

```
NSManagedObject *device2 = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"Devices =%@",devices);
[cell.lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device2 valueForKey:@"key1"]]];
[cell.lbl2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key2"]]];
[cell.lbl3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key3"]]];
[cell.lbl4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key4"]]];
[cell.lbl5 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key5"]]];
[cell.lbl6 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key6"]]];
[cell.lbl7 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key7"]]];
[cell.lbl8 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key8"]]];
[cell.lbl9 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device2 valueForKey:@"key9"]]];

Array1=[devices valueForKey:@"key1"];
Array2 =[devices valueForKey:@"key2"];
Array3 =[devices valueForKey:@"key3"];
Array4=[devices valueForKey:@"key4"];
Array5=[devices valueForKey:@"key5"];
Array6=[devices valueForKey:@"key6"];
Array7=[devices valueForKey:@"key7"];
Array8=[devices valueForKey:@"key8"];
Array9=[devices valueForKey:@"key9"];


NSLog(@" Array =%@",Array1);
NSLog(@" Array =%@",Array2);
NSLog(@" Array =%@",Array3);
NSLog(@"Array =%@",Array4);
NSLog(@" Array =%@",Array5);
NSLog(@"Array =%@",Array6);
NSLog(@"Array =%@",Array7);
NSLog(@"Array =%@",Array8);
```

This is how I convert array to string:

```
DevicesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Array componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
NSLog(@"Device String is  =%@",DevicesString);
```

Hear is the `NSLog` of `Array8`:

```
Array8 =(
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5
)
```

In array it is a string value.

I want to send the object of array one by one to the web service. Did I am doing right? When I am converting array to string it convert all the object of array to string.

Comment: Can you log any of Array so we can get idea what you are getting in that array ??

Comment: @CodeChanger Please see the updated question...

Comment: @Muju I don't understand what your issue is. You converted your string in `DevicesString` (you don't need to do stringWithFormat, you are already getting back an NSString) then what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Acutely I want to convert some array object to int and some array object to long.And I want to send it one by one.

Comment: Ok so you need to send data to server like {5,5,5,5} right ?

Comment: @CodeChanger One by One 5 then 5 and so on.

Comment: @CodeChanger without ",".

Comment: You can actually use a for-in loop to loop through the array elements and send

Comment: Why to send One by one. Create a comma separated string and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Wolverine Because web service need one by one value.

Comment: @Muju : That I understand, But rather then calling web service for each record in array One by one will take long time, Rather then that, send them as comma separated string, and Backend developer can create array from Coma separated string and perform operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comment you can send your data to server like below.

```
NSArray *arrayData = //fill your data.

for (NSString *strDevice in arrayData) {
     NSLog(@"Print Your Data = %@",strDevice);
     //Send this strDevice to server in loop one by one.
}
```

Hope this will helps you to send your data to serve one by one.

To Combine all array in One array use below code :

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray: Array1];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray: Array2];

and so on.
```

Above logic also can work but there is one more way to get all objects in single array and use same loop and send data to server.

```
NSMutableArray *allObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Add Your all devices array data directly in one array like below 

[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key1"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key2"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key3"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key4"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key5"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key6"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key7"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key8"]];
[allObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[devices valueForKey:@"key9"]];


for (NSString *strDevice in allObjectsArray) {
    NSLog(@"Print Your Data = %@",strDevice);
    //Send this strDevice to server in loop one by one.
}
```

Use above code for all object in single array.

> Note: As this is not preferable way to call service for these much
>   time although there is only one value you need to send on server so
>   make one string with comma separated and send it with single call.

Comment: Perfect I got my answer.

Comment: Great ! Happy Coding.

Comment: But this call only on array. How can I call other array in this loop.

Comment: @Muju : If you are thinking to call a web service for all 9 Array you mentioned in your code, You can try combining all arrays in One.

Comment: But This will not be good practise for sure. You should pass comma separated string and communicate with backend developer for same.

Comment: @Wolverine And then I need to split them.

Comment: Yes agree with Wolverine that if you need this all data push on server ask web service developer to make service who can read your comma separated string of devices and store into server DB.

Comment: I agree with @Wolverine. Having a server call for each and every element is not a good practise. Instead you can combine the data and send it using a single server call and backend developer can handle it

Comment: @Muju : in backend it is not that hard to convert Comma separated string in to array. it can be done by one or two line of code. Although for your first query posted in answer, I modify the above answer. Check the out.

Comment: Because from a normal user perspective having this much number of network calls will use a lot of his mobile data

Comment: @Wolverine can I create dictionary of that array and then send it to webservice.

Comment: @CodeChanger How can I add other array in your for loop??